# Apply for ESTA while in the US on expired J1 visa

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas

Currently on my grace period in the US. Is it possible to apply for an ESTA in Canada (drive through the border) and get a few months more in the US? Would there be any issues in entering Canada and clarifying I’ve left with my J1 visa. I have multiple nationalities, should I stick with the one of the expired Visa?

Comment: Using a different passport won't help: they'll ask if you have any other passports and, if so, to give the details of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enter the US under the visa waiver program by land, you don't actually need ESTA.  Also, there's no need to "clarify you've left with your J-1 visa" because once you've left the US your J-1 status ends, and because you're in your grace period you are not eligible to re-enter in J-1 status.

But to answer your real question, *yes, it is possible.*  There is a risk that you might not be admitted to the US, however.

You can also apply to remain in the US through a [change of nonimmigrant status](https://my.uscis.gov/exploremyoptions/change_non_immigrant_stay_us) to B-2.  This option is not available to J-1 nonimmigrants in a couple of cases, however:

> If you are an international exchange visitor (J-1 nonimmigrant), you may not apply to change your nonimmigrant status if:
>
> - You were admitted to the United States to receive graduate medical training, unless you receive a special waiver, or
> - You are an exchange visitor and are required to meet the foreign residence requirement, unless you receive a waiver.

Switching nationalities won't help you at all, and might cause the authorities to doubt your intentions.

Comment: I'd say there's a definite risk of not being readmitted on the grounds that the CBP officer thinks they're just coming back to continue whatever they were doing on their J-visa, which isn't allowed on VWP.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'd say that in general suspicions of immigrant intent are also more likely in such a case.